# Consulting if a record exist before inserting in Oracle

Tags: sql, select, insert, oracle11g

I'm developing a query in oracle which consults if certain record doesn't exist (SELECT) for making the INSERT step, this is my code

```sql
IF
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM HEX_KE_LOC WHERE CLVE_LOC = '20000')) = 0
THEN
    {INSERT INTO 
            HEX_KE_LOC (CLVE_LOC,CLVE_STDO,MUN,CLVE_PAIS,UID_BUS_UNI,CLVE_ALTR,DSC,CIT,ZIPCODE) 
    VALUES   
            ('20000','AGS','001','MX','0014','1','Zona Centro','01','20000');
      }
END IF;
```

but I can't make it work, any help I'll appreciate

Comment: Are you getting any error message? If so please edit your question to include it. I believe it is required that all derived tables be given an alias, e.g.: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM HEX_KE_LOC WHERE CLVE_LOC = '20000') AS record_check`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way to do this is with a `MERGE` statement with no update clause:

```
MERGE INTO HEX_KE_LOC USING dual
   ON ( CLVE_LOC = '20000' )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (CLVE_LOC,CLVE_STDO,MUN,CLVE_PAIS,UID_BUS_UNI,CLVE_ALTR,DSC,CIT,ZIPCODE) 
    VALUES ('20000','AGS','001','MX','0014','1','Zona Centro','01','20000');
```